# supports screen doesnt work?

Tags: android

I want to restrict my app to 10.1 tablets only. Below is the manifest configuration for that.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I am able to run the app with Emulator 4.0.3(HVGA).
can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think this restriction works for displaying applications on Google market and for real devices.

Answer (score 0):

This restrictions is only to Google Play filter. You can try by `android:minSDKVersion` attribute, like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" >
</uses-sdk>
```

This could help you.